# How to merge several columns as one column for a table like this?

Tags: tables, columns, multirow, multicolumn

How can I edit this table in order to have one column, for example, let's say I have this table:

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\newcommand{\cenMultlCell}[2][c]{\begin{tabular}[#1]{@{}l@{}}#2\end{tabular}}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, linkcolor=black]{hyperref}
\newcommand{\tabitem}{~~\llap{\textbullet}~~}




\begin{document}



\begin{table}
    \footnotesize\centering % needed, as table is to wide
    \begin{tabular}{lS[table-format=2.2]SS} % supposing that you want to put numbers in the emty cells
        \toprule
        something & \multicolumn{3}{c}{aproach} \\\cmidrule(l){2-4}
        something  &{one} & {two} & {three} \\\midrule


        \textbullet~bullet one 
        %dummy
        %& {\cenMultlCell{text1:~33.68\\ text2:~33.92\\ text3:~34.31\\ text4:~33.68\\ text4:~34.19\\ text5:~66.31\\ text6:~33.68\\  text3:~21.53}}
        %RBF
        & {\cenMultlCell{text1:46.96\\ text2:~30.02\\ text3:~45.22\\ text4:~46.96\\ text4:~22.06\\ text5:~53.03\\ text6:~46.96\\  text3:~10.50}} 
        %polinomial
        & {\cenMultlCell{44.63\\27.55\\ 46.37\\44.37\\ 19.92\\ 55.36\\ 44.63\\  10.03}}
        %Lineal
        & {\cenMultlCell{82.86\\ 80.83\\ 84.31\\ 82.86\\85.56\\17.13\\82.86\\78.22}}
\\\midrule

            %RBF
        \cenMultlCell{\textbullet~bullet one \\ \textbullet~bullet two \\}
        & {\cenMultlCell{text1:47.08\\ text2:30.14\\ text3:45.17\\ text4:~47.86\\ text4:~22.17\\ text5:~52.91\\ text6:~47.08\\  text3:~10.53}} 
        %polinomial
        & {\cenMultlCell{44.87\\ 27.79\\ 46.26\\ 44.87\\ 20.13\\ 55.12\\ 44.87\\ 10.08}}
        %lineal
        & {\cenMultlCell{92.65\\ 92.44\\ 91.60\\ 92.44\\93.08\\ 0.73\\ 92.65\\  92.85}}
\\\midrule

        \cenMultlCell{\textbullet~bullet one \\ \textbullet~bullet two \\ \textbullet~bullet Three\\}
        & 
        %rbf
        {\cenMultlCell{text1:~45.68\\ text2:~28.65\\ text3:~45.86\\ text4:~45.86\\ text4:~20.87\\ text5:~54.31\\ text6:~45.68\\  text3:~10.25}} 
        %polinomial
        & {\cenMultlCell{45.10\\ 28.04\\ 46.14\\ 45.10\\20.34\\ 54.89\\ 45.10\\  10.13}}
        %lineal
        & {\cenMultlCell{65.03\\ 59.28\\ 64.08\\ 65.03\\72.38\\ 34.96\\ 65.03\\ 46.55}}
\\\midrule


        \cenMultlCell{\textbullet~bullet one \\ \textbullet~bullet two \\ \textbullet~bullet Three\\ \textbullet~bullet four\\}
        %rbf
        & {\cenMultlCell{text1:~44.63\\ text2:~27.55\\ text3:~46.37\\ text4:~44.63\\ text4:~19.92\\ text5:~55.36\\ text6:~44.63\\  text3:~10.03}} 
        %polinomial
        & {\cenMultlCell{47.55\\ 30.64\\ 44.94\\ 47.55\\ 22.61\\ 52.44\\ 47.55\\  10.62}}
        %lineal
        & {\cenMultlCell{93.12\\ 92.99\\ 94.36\\ 93.12\\ 93.12\\ 0.06\\93.12\\ 94.07}}
\\\midrule

        %Total: & 909 & 2323& 32332& \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\caption{your caption}\label{tab:label}
\end{table}





A reference to \autoref{tab:label}.
\end{document}
```

I would like to leave just one of this:

```
text1:
text2:
text3:
text4:
text4:
text5:
text6:
text3:
```

So the desired output would be:

I would like to get a new column which is the `text1` to `text8` one and this space:

```
---------------------|
                     ↓


                       one    two   three
              text1:  number number number  
              text2:  number number number  
              text3:  number number number  
bullet one    text4:  number number number  
              text5:  number number number  
              text6:  number number number  
              text7:  number number number  
              text8:  number number number 

              text1:  number number number  
              text2:  number number number  
bullet one    text3:  number number number  
bullet two    text4:  number number number  
              text5:  number number number  
              text6:  number number number  
              text7:  number number number  
              text8:  number number number 

              text1:  number number number  
              text2:  number number number  
bullet one    text3:  number number number  
bullet two    text4:  number number number  
nullet three  text5:  number number number  
              text6:  number number number  
              text7:  number number number  
              text8:  number number number 

              text1:  number number number  
              text2:  number number number  
              text3:  number number number  
bullet one    text4:  number number number  
bullet two    text5:  number number number  
bullet three  text6:  number number number  
bullet four   text7:  number number number  
              text8:  number number number
```

So far I tried giving it a space with `~` but it doesnt work any idea of how to aproach this or modify the above table in order to get this new column?. Thanks in advance guys!

Update:

I tried @DoubleYou aproach and I got this:

[image]

Any idea of how to fix it?. Thanks for the support guys

Comment: To be honest, I don't really understand this question now I've read it again. What is meant to go where? How is the target structure related to the current structure? (Why 2 text4 and text3 after text6 and which text1 goes where? Where do the one, two, three numbers come from for each line?)

Comment: Sorry @cfr This is too visual I am making my best to explain the situation, I edited the desirec output. As you can see column `one`, `two` and `three` have the `textn` as a column I just would like to leave the numbers and one `textn` column. Thanks for the help

Comment: I edited guys, Sorry if I was not clear!

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use a simple `tabular` (or `longtable`) together with `multirow`? The following gives you the same result as your outlined example (both longtable and tabular are used, you can choose whichever you want). Any empty rows or other table formatting can be easily added.

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{lllll}
    \caption{A table with a lot of numbers.}\label{tbl:numbers1} \\
    \hline
    && one & two & three \\
    \multirow{8}{*}{bullet one} & text1: & number & number & number \\
                                                            & text2: & number & number & number \\
                                                            & text3: & number & number & number \\
                                                            & text4: & number & number & number \\
                                                            & text5: & number & number & number \\
                                                            & text6: & number & number & number \\
                                                            & text7: & number & number & number \\
                                                            & text8: & number & number & number \\
    \hline
    \multirow{8}{*}{\parbox{2cm}{bullet one \\ bullet two}} & text1: & number & number & number \\
                                                            & text2: & number & number & number \\
                                                            & text3: & number & number & number \\
                                                            & text4: & number & number & number \\
                                                            & text5: & number & number & number \\
                                                            & text6: & number & number & number \\
                                                            & text7: & number & number & number \\
                                                            & text8: & number & number & number \\
    \hline \endhead
    \hline \endfoot
    \hline \endlastfoot
\end{longtable}

\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{lllll}
    \hline
    && one & two & three \\
    \multirow{8}{*}{bullet one} & text1: & number & number & number \\
                                                            & text2: & number & number & number \\
                                                            & text3: & number & number & number \\
                                                            & text4: & number & number & number \\
                                                            & text5: & number & number & number \\
                                                            & text6: & number & number & number \\
                                                            & text7: & number & number & number \\
                                                            & text8: & number & number & number \\
    \hline
    \multirow{8}{*}{\parbox{2cm}{bullet one \\ bullet two}} & text1: & number & number & number \\
                                                            & text2: & number & number & number \\
                                                            & text3: & number & number & number \\
                                                            & text4: & number & number & number \\
                                                            & text5: & number & number & number \\
                                                            & text6: & number & number & number \\
                                                            & text7: & number & number & number \\
                                                            & text8: & number & number & number \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{A table with a lot of numbers.}\label{tbl:numbers2}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. This is almost the aproach I was looking for. The problem with this is that the table is overlaping. Any idea of how to fix this issue?.

Comment: What do you mean with 'the table is overlapping'? Running the example does not produce any overlap as far as I can see.

Comment: I edited the status of the question, thanks for the help!

Comment: That's not an overlap. Those are simply two tables: one is a `longtable` and the other is a regular `tabular`. The `longtable` aligns differently on a page, but allows for tables to be really long, which I think yours will be. Any alignment, captioning and so on is all for you to do as that is not the question you asked. You simply have to choose and edit one of them with your content. I do suggest to read up on how tables in LaTeX work (maybe [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables)).

Comment: Sorry I thought you create one table instead of two. Thanks